# mat-select panel still shows overlapped like version 14 and below even after upgrade to angular material 15

Tags: angular, angular-material

we have used mat-select in our project, the panel shows overlapping on the trigger text like version 14 and before (material version 12 was used in our project)

[image]

after finding few hacks, the panel showed below the trigger text, but it was not consistent with different screen sizes, specially the mobile view.

We found that from material version 15, the select panel showed below the trigger text - [image]

so we upgraded to material version 15, and also upgraded the angular version to 15. But even after the upgrade the mat-select is still showing in the previous style.

Can someone please suggest what could be going wrong here and what needs to be done to get working like material version 15 mat-select

Comment: Did you do the migration ? cause you might be running on legacy components which will be removed in ng 17. Just for context https://rc.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration

Comment: yes, did the update using 
ng update @angular/material@15

Comment: OK then you have not done migration yet, so you running all the components in legacy mode and style wise its near identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, you have only updated to Angular material 15, but is running in legacy mode.

To fully migrate you need to run.

schematic: `ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration`

however due to class name changes to the mdc- prefix etc and structual changes in some of the componets. you should follow their migration guide.

https://rc.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration

Comment: Thanks, this worked, after running this command, it removed the legacy imports and made some changes in the component html file.
The overall styles have been affected, but atleast now the mat-select is behaving proper as we wanted.